# Can I create an Array of Char pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to C, and things are different in C than in any other language I've learned. In my homework I want to create an array of chars which point to an array of chars, but rather than make a multidimensional char array, I figure I'd have more control and create char arrays and put each individual one into the indexes of the original char array:

```
char keywords[10];
keywords[0] = "float";
```

The above example is to clarify and a simple case. But my question is due to the research I've been doing, and I am confused about something. Normally this would work in other languages, but in C it would be:

```
char *keyword[10];
keywords[0] = "float";
```

But when I want to send it through a function, why is this necessary:

```
void function(char **keyword); //function prototype
```

Wouldn't just passing the array pointer be enough?

Comment: What do you think/expect that function prototype should be?

Comment: You could also pass char *keyword[], means exactly the same thing

Comment: Yes, you can .... do what you want.  But the real question is what good C programming books have you read....

Comment: Well thats what I am asking, I saw this in someone else's question, but the two stars ** are confusing.

Comment: I have read no books, just research online. In the class the professor throws us under a bus and makes us learn different languages. I come from a java, php background.

Comment: Yea, I saw that too @Matthieu though, why does this need to be explicitly said when the memory in the first array is only a pointer?

Comment: Andy, the strings consume memory and the array values *point* to that memory.  The array values themselves consume memory, and the array pointer *points* to that memory.  The array pointer points to memory which contains a pointer which points to the string in memory.  Pointers to pointers are \*\*.  The array pointer, unless stored in a variable, does not have a pointer pointing to it -- it's embedded in your object code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you're confused by the double stars in

```
void function(char ** keyword);
```

The double stars just means that **this function expects you to pass a pointer to a pointer to a char**.  This syntax doesn't include any information about the fact that you are using an array, or that the char is actually the first char of many in a string.  It's up to you as the programmer to know what kind of data structure this `char **` actually points to.

For example, let's suppose the beginning of your array is stored at address 0x1000.  The `keyword` argument to the function should have a value of 0x1000.  If you dereference `keyword`, you get the first entry in the array, which is a `char *` that points to the first char in the string "float".  If you dereference the `char *`, you get the char "f".

The (contrived) code for that would look like:

```
void function(char **keyword)
{
    char * first_string = *keyword;   // *keyword is equivalent to keyword[0]
    char first_char = *first_string;  // *first_string is equivalent to first_string[0]
}
```

There were two pointers in the example above.  By adding an offset to the first pointer before dereferencing it, you can access different strings in the array.  By adding an offset to the second pointer before dereferencing it, you can access different chars in the string.

Comment: I see what you are saying.Its a little confusing with the stars, but I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Adding a star to a type T just changes it to "pointer to T".  So "char *" is "pointer to char" and "char **" is "pointer to pointer to char".

Answer (score 2):

```
char *keyword[10];
```

`keyword` is an array 10 of `char *`. In a value context, it converted to a pointer to a `char *`.

This conversion is a part of what Chris Torek calls **"The Rule"**:

> "As noted elsewhere, C has a very important rule about arrays and pointers. This rule -- The Rule -- says that, in a value context, an object of type ‘array of T’ becomes a value of type ‘pointer to T’, pointing to the first element of that array"

See here for more information: http://web.torek.net/torek/c/pa.html

The C-FAQ also has an entry on this array to pointer conversion:

> Question 6.3: So what is meant by the "equivalence of pointers and arrays'' in C?

http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html

Comment: This is correct, but not very clear to someone new to the language.  You should consider explaining what you mean by a "value context".

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can't really pass array to a function. Instead, you pass a pointer to the beginning of the array. Since you have array of `char*`, the function will get a pointer to `char*`, which is `char**`.

If you want, you can write (in the prototype) `char *keyword[]` instead of `char **keyword`. The compiler will automatically convert it.

Also, in C you can dereference pointers like arrays, so you loose almost nothing with that "converting to pointer".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to

```
void function(char **keyword);
```

Andy, think about that an array is just a pointer(to the beginning of the array), that's why you write:

```
void function(char **keyword);
```

Because you have create an array to char pointers.

If it's easier to understand try:

```
void function(char *keyword[]);
```

But it's more C standard to use the first one, though if you use a C++ compiler won't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        char *CharPtr[3];
        char a[4]="abc";
        char b[4]="def";
        char c[4]="ghi";
        CharPtr[0]=a;
        CharPtr[1]=b;
        CharPtr[2]=c;

        printf("\n content of CharPtr[0] =%s",CharPtr[0]);
        printf("\n content of CharPtr[1] =%s",CharPtr[1]);
        printf("\n content of CharPtr[2] =%s\n",CharPtr[2]);

        printf(" \n content of char a[4]=%s",a);
        printf(" \n content of char b[4]=%s",b);
        printf(" \n content of char c[4]=%s\n",c);
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what was asked in the question...I think you should read the question first carefully....

Answer (score 0):

`char *keywords[10]` is an array of character pointers. So `keywords[0]`, `keywords[1]`.. and so on will have the addresses to different character arrays.

In `printf` you can use `%s` and `keywords[0]` to print the entire character array whose address(i.e. address of the first byte in the array) is stored at `keywords[0]`.

While passing to a function, if you give `*keywords`, you are referring to the *value at(address stored at `keywords[0]`)* which is again an address. So, to get the value instead of address, you can add another `*`... Hope that clarifies a bit..

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are assigning your first string:

```
"float"
```

to the first index position of keyword[0]

```
char keyword[0] = "float";
```

which is the first index position of the array:

```
char keyword[10];
```

If the previous is the case, then in a sense, you are essentially creating a data structure that holds a data structure. The array of any type is the 'smallest' data structure of that type in C. Considering that in your example you are creating a character array, then you are actually utilizing the smallest data type (char=1bit) at each index position of the smallest built in data structure (the array).

With that said, if in your example, you are attempting to create an array of arrays; your character array

```
/* Hold ten characters total */
char keyword[10];
```

was designed to hold 10 characters. One at each index position (which you probably already know). So after declaring the array titled keyword, you then try to initialize the first index position of the array with another (the second) character array:

```
/* I believe this is what you had stated */
char keywords[0] = "float";
```

With the second character array having an index of 5 positions in size.

In order to achieve your desired goal, you would essentially be creating an array that basically emulates the effect of a data structure that 'holds' other data structures.

NOTE: If you had/have plans on trying to create a data structure that holds a data structure that holds a data structure. A.K.A. a triple nested data structure and in this case I think that would be a Matrix, WHICH I WOULDN'T RECOMMEND!

None the less, the matrix structure would be in the form of the first index position of keyword, being assigned the whole array of keywords, which would include all of the data stored in each index position of the keywords array. Then there would something probably like: keywords1, keywords2, ... keywords9,

which would essentially emulate the form of:

```
char *keyword[10] = { 
                        char *keywords0[10] = {"float", etc, etc, etc.};
                        char *keywords1[10] = {"keyword1", "secondIndexOfThisArray", etc, etc, etc.}; 
                       and so

                   };
```

So basically from right to left, the keyword array, is an array of pointers that points to array of pointers that points to character arrays.

If that is what you are representing you would be better defining a custom data type of struct/record, and with in that custom structure you would want to define a subordinate or child level of structures. You could also pre-declare them then initialize them.

e.g.

```
typedef *nestedDataStructures {

    struct keyWords[];
    struct keyWords1[];
    struct keyWords2[];

    ... and so on.
}; nestedDataStructures
```

Instead of adding ten structs to one custom structure I would break down into 3 or 4 (how ever many structures and use) and create a module in order to yield symmetrical layers of abstraction as you manipulate your data set.

None the less, you can not create the character array and potentially assign the other character array in the fashion that you did (or who knows maybe you can), but the way you would want to emulate the array that holds arrays, is to create a character pointer array up front, of X number index positions and then initialize then use the character arrays in the form of a strings declared with in the initialization of the original declaration.

So basically you could declare your whole array upfront, then with in your program design, either dereference each index position, use assignment, or print/write the index position.

Like for instance you could always do something like this:

```
/* Example of the program and declaration with out a function */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    /* 
     * A character pointer array that contains multiple 
     * character arrays.
     */

    char *grewMe[2] = {"I want to ", "grow to be bigger"};

    int w = 0;

    for(; w < 2;) {
        printf("%s", grewMe[w]);
        ++w;
    }

    printf(" :-)\n");
    w = 0;
    return 0;
}
// Output:
// I want to grow to be bigger :-)
```

Or something like this:

```
/* Example of program: function passed arguments 
 * of a pointer to the array of pointers 
 */
#include <stdio.h>

void mygrowth(char *growMe[]);

int main(){

    char *growMe[2] = {"I want to ", "grow to be bigger"};

    mygrowth(growMe);  
    printf(" :-)\n");

    return 0;

}
void mygrowth(char *growMe[])
{

    int w = 0;
    for (; w < 2;) {
        printf("%s", growMe[w]);
        ++w;
    } 
}
```

The assignment of each index position as it's passed as an argument:

```
/* 
 * This program compiles, runs and outputs properly
 * Example of a program with a function of 
 * arguments pnt2pnter 
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void thoughtAsAFunction(char **iThink);

int main()
{

    char *iThink[10] = {"I am trying to grow, but it's a hard task to ",
                        "accomplish. My father is short ", 
                        "my mother is even shorter than him, ", 
                        "what is the probability of me getting taller? ", 
                        "Well both my grandfather's were Six ",
                        "Foot Five, and both my grandmother's ", 
                        "were over 5 foot 8 inches tall! If my ",  
                        "grandparent's genes point to my parents, and my ", 
                        "parent's genes point to mine I might have a chance ",
                        "of being 6 foot. Do you know what I mean? "};

    thoughtAsAFunction(iThink);

    printf(":-)\n");

    return 0;
}
void thoughtAsAFunction(char **iThink) {

    int andy = 0;
    for (; andy < 10;) {
        char * pntThroughPnt = iThink[andy];
        printf("%s", pntThroughPnt);
        ++andy;
    }
    andy = 0;
}
```

Or pass by reference, with an increment of the loop count variable:

```
/*
 * This program compiles, runs, and outputs all of the character
 * arrays. 
 * 
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void thoughtAsAFunction(char **iThink);

int main()
{

    char *iThink[10] = {"I am trying to grow, but it's a hard task to ",
                        "accomplish. My father is short ", 
                        "my mother is even shorter than him, ", 
                        "what is the probability of me getting taller? ", 
                        "Well both my grandfather's were Six ",
                        "Foot Five, and both my grandmother's ", 
                        "were over 5 foot 8 inches tall! If my ",  
                        "grandparent's genes point to my parents, and my ", 
                        "parent's genes point to mine, then I might have a chance ",
                        "of being 6 foot. Do you know what I mean? "};

    int andy = 0;
    for (; andy < 10;) {
        // pass by reference and increment.
        thoughtAsAFunction(&iThink[andy]);
        ++andy;

    }

    printf(":-)\n");
    andy = 0;

    return 0;
}
void thoughtAsAFunction(char **iThink) {

    char * pntThroughPnt = *iThink;
    printf("%s", pntThroughPnt);

}
```

Keep in mind that this is the case if you declare the array of pointers (char *array[10];), and each pointer points to an array of characters.