# Structs 'const char *x' vs 'char x[30]'

Tags: c, struct

Hi sorry I've been stuck on this code for a while and both seem to work I just don't really understand the differences.

```
struct faveThings{

  const char *favFood; 
  const char *faveFriend;


};

struct dog{

 const char name[20];
 const char breed[20];
 int height;
 int weight;

 struct faveThings dogFaves;

};
```

I can completely understand the dog struct the use of 'char name[20]' makes complete sense to me. But with faveThings I struggle with 'char *favFood', I get that this is a pointer, but how can this hold a string if its just a char? Should it not be an array of chars?

```
const char *favFood[20];
```

Thanks for any help i've been banging my head against the wall for hours trying to find the difference.

Answer (score 6):

`favFood` doesn't hold a string. It points somewhere. And one can make it point to a character that is the first one *in* a string. By convention, since the c strings can have different length, they are terminated with a `'\0'` character. That way, even if all you have is a pointer to the first character, you can find the end of the string.

So a library function like `strlen` will use the pointer to go from the first character to each subsequent one, until it finds the NUL character.

`const char *favFood[20];` is a completely different beast. It's an array of 20 pointers. Each pointer can point to something different.

Comment: I get that it points somewhere, but I don't understand how this can be used to retrieve a string, for example i can use it to hold "Meat" and return it with 'theDog.dogFaves.favFood', shouldn't this just return a single char 'M' rather than the string?

Comment: @MGordon0405 - `theDog.dogFaves.favFood` doesn't return anything. It **evaluates** to the address of the first character in the string, and not to the character itself.

Comment: @MGordon0405 - Forget strings for now. Do you understand why to pass an array of integers to a function, a pointer to the first element and the array length is all that's needed?

Comment: Ah yes, thank you I think I understand whats happening now. Basically it points to the first char and then gets the rest of the chars based off the length. If that's not right please correct me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MGordon0405 - Yes you are grasping it. For strings however, the terminating NUL convention is in place to avoid having to pass the length all over the place. That way, a simple pointer is enough to denote a string

Comment: @StoryTeller nice explanation, especially in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that `const char *favFood;` does point to a single `char`, but it is understood that there will be a block of memory containing consecutive `char`s, and that pointer points to the first one.  So the code can use that pointer to access all of the `char`s in the block.

The code that uses `favFood` will also involve performing a memory allocation, filling up that memory with chars (and a null terminator), and seeing `favFood` to point into that allocation.

`const char *favFood[20];` would be an array of 20 pointers.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you that makes sense. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

`const char *favFood[20]` is an array of pointers pointing towards a character data.

It's Like

```
*favFood[1] -------->MemLocation(0x001) = a
*favFood[2] -------->MemLocation(0x002) = b
```

and so on please take a look here also: [Can I create an Array of Char pointers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352555/can-i-create-an-array-of-char-pointers-in-c)

I hope that answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Below is an array of constant characters.  It actually contains five elements, because the C language adds a '\0' at the end of the string delimited by the `"` symbols.  In C, an array object, such as `MEAT` is actually a pointer to the first element of the array, so MEAT is actually a memory address not the entire array of characters!

```
const char[] MEAT = "Meat";
```

Below is a pointer to a `const char`.  The `*` symbol tells you that it is a pointer.  (It doesn't matter if you put the star by the type being pointed to or by the name of the variable.  This can be confusing, so I usually keep the type information together and have the name on its own, but I believe this is not the most usual convention.)  The `favFood` variable is initialised with the address of the first character in the `MEAT` array.  (Remember that `MEAT` is a memory address, so this is setting one memory address to equal another.)

```
const char* favFood = MEAT;
```

At some point in the future, your animal may suddenly decide that it no longer likes meat and now it actually prefers biscuits (more likely for a cat to change its mind than a dog, I know, but this is just an example).

```
const char BISCUITS[] = "Biscuits";

/* Some code is done here, until you find... */

favFood = BISCUITS;
```

Now, both `MEAT` and `BISCUITS` are constant, which means you cannot change them, but `favFood` is not itself constant but points to a constant string (the first character in the string anyway), so you can change it!

You can also have non-constant strings:

```
char nameAndFaveFood[50];
sprintf(nameAndFaveFood, "%.26s likes %.9s best.", name, favFood);
```

... but make sure you don't copy more characters - including the terminating '\0' null character - than you have allocated space, in this case 49 characters and a terminator.  This is why the `sprint` function has precision specifiers to limit the length of the sub-strings.

And you can have constant pointers to changeable memory.

```
char* const LIKES_FOOD = &nameAndFaveFood[27];
```

Note that the `LIKES_FOOD` object is initialised to point part way through the `nameAndFaveFood` array.  It will always point at that address.  You can call the routine in the previous code block with different `name` and `favFood` parameters, but `LIKES_FOOD` will always point to the 28th character in the `nameAndFaveFood` array.